# TS "Cannot find name" dissapear only while polyfills.ts is open

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have an project in Angular 10 and got strange TS (TSLint) bug. In Visual Studio Code everywhere where I use `$localize` I got error with message `Cannot find name '$localize'.ts(2304)` but when I open `polyfills.ts` file in new tab (in this file `$localize` is imported to project `import '@angular/localize/init';`) error dissapear and `$localize` is typed. It's probably TSLint or VSC issue because Angular compiler works good and project runs. It's not critical issue but bit frustrating. Is something I missed in poject or VSC config?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/36757#issuecomment-660318825 or https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/36757#issuecomment-660547819 might help

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me. Literally just delete the .vs directory located at the same level as your solution file.

I saw this post
https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2018/Aug/07/Fixing-Visual-Studio-Intellisense-Errors